# append list items to OL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initial list:

```
<OL>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</OL>

<A> LINK </A>
```

the link fires a ajax request which gets data in html format, like the list above:

```
<OL>
  <li> ... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</OL>
```

How can I take the `LI`'s from the ajax response and append them to the initial list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get('whatever', function (html)
{
    $(html).find('li').appendTo('ol').
});
```

Comment: Won't this append aditional li's to the existing li's instead of the ol?